# Servlet not directing to JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jdbc

We are required to write a Web application using Java, HTML, Beans, and JSPs. The problem is I have never taken a HTML or CSS course.

I have a base HTML page called index.html that takes a user's first and last name in a text field with a submit button. When I press submit I get a "Page cannot be displayed error." I have compared my code with my instructors and it is very similar so I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, do not mind my horrible formatting.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Final Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Banking by Tyler Weaver</h1>
        <h4>Please Enter your First and Last Name</h4>
        <form action="BankingControl" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Menu">   
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" required/> <br></>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="LastName" required/> <br></>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>  
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

BankingControl.java

```
import beans.User;
import database.MySQL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import utilities.ErrorLogger;

@WebServlet(name = "BankingControl", urlPatterns = {"/BankingControl"})
public class BankingControl extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String mysqlPrefix = "jdbc:mysql://";
    private static final String hostname = "cs3db.bloomu.edu";
    private static final String databaseName = "CS3";
    private static final String databaseURL = mysqlPrefix + hostname + "/" + databaseName;
    private static final String userName = "tgw46366";
    private static final String password = "tgw46366";

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        //Creates mysql database connection with specified information
        MySQL mysql = new MySQL(databaseURL, userName, password);

        //The URL where processor will send.
        String JSP_URL = "/index.html";

        //Tries making a connection to the database
        try (Connection conn = mysql.getConnection()) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Database Connection Obtained");

            //Retrieve action from page
            String action = request.getParameter("action").trim();
            //If action is null, make it menu
            if (action == null) {
                action = "Menu";
            }

            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName").trim());
            user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName").trim());
            request.setAttribute("User", user);

            //Check to see if action is menu
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Menu")) {
                //Place to send information
                JSP_URL = "/Menu.jsp";

                ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "
                        + user.getLastName()
                        + " logged in - Menu Page Returned");
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("NewCustomer")) {
                JSP_URL = "/NewCustomer.jsp";

                ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "New Customer Selected");
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("NewAccount")) {
                JSP_URL = "/NewAccount.jsp";

                ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "New Account Selected");
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("AccountTransaction")) {
                JSP_URL = "/Transaction.jsp";

                ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Account Transaction Selected");
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Logout")) {
                JSP_URL = "/index.html";

                ErrorLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Logout Selected");
            } else {
                ErrorLogger.log(Level.WARNING,
                        "Invalid Option -- index.html Returned");
            }

            //If connection cannot be made, throw here
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Not Making a Database Connection at this Time", ex);
        }

        //forward to correct JSP
        getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(JSP_URL)
                .forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

MySQL.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import utilities.ErrorLogger;

public class MySQL {

    private final String databaseURL;
    private final String userName;
    private final String password;

    public MySQL(String databaseURL, String userName, String password) {
        this.databaseURL = databaseURL;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        initDB();
    }

    private void initDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); //Not needed for MySQL - here for show only
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find the class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \n"
                    + "Program will now exit. ", ex);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not instaniate the class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \n"
                    + "Program will now exit. ", ex);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not access the class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \n"
                    + "Program will now exit. ", ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, userName, password);
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not connect to the database. "
                    + "Database string = "
                    + databaseURL + " user =  " + userName + " password " + password, ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, userName, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not connect to the database. "
                    + "Database string = "
                    + databaseURL + " user =  " + userName + " password " + password);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "SQL Exception is thrown while "
                        + "trying to close a Connection object. The connection "
                        + "object was not null.", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ErrorLogger.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ErrorLogger {

    private static final String errorFileName = "SQLErrorLogger";
    public static boolean showLogInErrorWindow = true;

    private static Logger errorLogger;

    private static void initializeLogging() throws IOException {
        String logFile = getLogfileName();
        errorLogger = Logger.getLogger(logFile);
        Handler handler = new FileHandler(logFile);
        handler.setFormatter(new java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter());
        if (showLogInErrorWindow) {
            errorLogger.setUseParentHandlers(true);
        } else {
            errorLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        }
        errorLogger.addHandler(handler);
    }

    private static String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
        DateFormat format;
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

        return (format.format(date));
    }

    private static String getFormattedTime(Date date) {
        DateFormat format;
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.a");

        return (format.format(date));
    }

    private static String getDateTime(Date date) {
        String sDateTime = getFormattedDate(date) + "_"
                + getFormattedTime(date);
        return sDateTime;
    }

    private static String getLogfileName() {
        String logFileName = errorFileName;

        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String sFormattedDateTime = getDateTime(date);
        logFileName += "_" + sFormattedDateTime;
        logFileName += ".log";

        return logFileName;
    }

    public static String getNewLogFileName(String logFileBase, String logFileExt) {
        String logFile = logFileBase;
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String sFormattedDateTime = getDateTime(date);
        logFile += "_" + sFormattedDateTime;
        logFile += logFileExt;
        return logFile;
    }

    public static void log(Level level, String message, Throwable ex) {
        if (errorLogger == null) {
            initLogger();
        }
        errorLogger.log(level, message, ex);
    }

    public static void log(Level level, String message) {
        if (errorLogger == null) {
            initLogger();
        }
        errorLogger.log(level, message);
    }

    private static void initLogger() {
        try {
            initializeLogging();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            errorLogger = Logger.getLogger(getLogfileName());//Will not write to a file
            errorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not create a file handler for teh error logger");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ErrorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Test error Message");
    }

}
```

This Should be the minimum required to reproduce what is wrong aside from the sample database and information. All of the JSP pages load individually but It will not start from index.html. It makes it difficult to debug the rest of the application. Any help will be appreciated.

Directory:[image: Director img]

---

Image of errors![image: First image]

[image: ErrorImage]

Comment: You should provide web.xml to be complete and what you mean by error (check in console - server returned error or browser did not want to connect at all). Guys, show minimum effort please!

Comment: I would want to see the directory structure and other controllers that you might have. You are redirecting to a resource, but I don't know if that resource is located in the same directory as root or is it somewhere else? Cheers.

Comment: @MichalWilkowski How do I show web.xml? I will list my directory structure above!

Comment: btw when going from index.html to a jsp is your url as you expect it? I have a feeling that your forward is relative as opposed to absolute and so it actually sends to an incorrect url.

Comment: I go from index.html to the BankingControl servlet which will direct it to a jsp. I have the URLs down exactly as my instructor put them while using the same structure.

Comment: So you wanted: /FinalProject/BankingControl/NewCustomer.jsp?

Comment: Well index.html is supposed to redirect to Menu.jsp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66285/discussion-between-user1598503-and-tyler-weaver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put an answer here in case someone is running into this. The problem was an internal server error that occurred due to missing jars.